# MongoDB Compass disconnects immediately

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass, studio3t

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB with MongoDB Compass 1.20.4

My connection string is:

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/?replicaSet=rs0
```

Here is my MongoDB docker setup:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo0:
    hostname: mongo0
    container_name: mongo0
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    restart: always
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0" ]
  mongo1:
    hostname: mongo1
    container_name: mongo1
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27018:27017
    restart: always
    entrypoint: [ "/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all", "--replSet", "rs0" ]
  mongosetup:
    hostname: mongosetup
    container_name: mongosetup
    image: mongo
    depends_on:
      - mongo0
      - mongo1
    volumes:
      - ./scripts/:/scripts
    restart: "no"
    entrypoint: [ "bash", "/scripts/mongo-setup.sh" ]
```

mongo-setup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 10
mongo --host mongo0:27017 <<EOF
  var config={"_id":"rs0","members":[{"_id":0,"host":"mongo0:27017"},{"_id":1,"host":"mongo1:27017"}]};
  rs.initiate(config);
EOF
```

Here is what I see in my docker logs:

```
mongo0            | 2020-02-02T14:42:35.114+0000 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 172.27.0.1:55494 #31 (4 connections now open)
mongo0            | 2020-02-02T14:42:35.115+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn31] received client metadata from 172.27.0.1:55494 conn31: { driver: { name: "nodejs", version: "3.4.0" }, os: { type: "Darwin", name: "darwin", architecture: "x64", version: "19.3.0" }, platform: "'Node.js v10.2.0, LE (unified)", application: { name: "MongoDB Compass" } }
mongo0            | 2020-02-02T14:42:35.120+0000 I  NETWORK  [conn31] end connection 172.27.0.1:55494 (3 connections now open)
```

Prior to using replica set it connected just fine, also Studio 3T works perfectly with this setup. Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Changing `Read Preference` in MongoDB Compass to `Primary Preferred` fixed the connection issue.
2. Then I noticed that I cannot modify/delete anything from the GUI, basically I was connected via read-only mode. After looking closely at MongoDB logs I noticed that my PRIMARY set was available at port 27018 and not 27017 I connected to.

I tweaked my `mongo-setup.sh` to always make set at port 27017 PRIMARY (set priority option):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/force-member-to-be-primary/
sleep 10
mongo --host mongo0:27017 <<EOF
  var config={"_id":"rs0","members":[{"_id":0,"host":"mongo0:27017","priority":1},{"_id":1,"host":"mongo1:27017", "priority":0.5}]};
  rs.initiate(config);
EOF
echo 'Finished mongo setup'
```

Links for reference:
[Replica Set Elections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-elections/)

[Force a Member to Become Primary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/force-member-to-be-primary/)